# Pass callback Function as Parameter to Widget while keeping Lint Rules "argument_type_not_assignable"

Tags: flutter, dart, lint, linter, dart-analyzer

In my widget I pass a function callback as a parameter to the widget:

```
onTap: onTapRestaurantItemCallback
```

Out in the screen widget, which contains the widget above, I then execute the function callback:

```
onTapRestaurantItemCallback: () { // Handling the callback method }
```

I am using Lint for Dart/Flutter to check my code:
https://pub.dev/packages/lint

The linter is not happy with my function parameter and gives me an error, I am violating the rule:

```
argument_type_not_assignable
```

"The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'"
https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#argument_type_not_assignable

<strike>Apparently the problem is that the widgets "onTap" expects void, whereas the callback returns a Future.</strike>

I can make the error go away in the widget by writing:

```
onTap: () => onTapRestaurantItemCallback
```

But then my function callbacks stop working.

**Do you know how I can pass a function callback to my widget like I do and still keep the
argument_type_not_assignable
lint rule?**

Below I paste a more full code on the scenario I have described above:

```
// WIDGET USED BY OTHER WIDGET BELOW
class RestaurantItem extends StatelessWidget {
  // FUNCTION CALLBACK
  final Function onTapRestaurantItemCallback;
  const RestaurantItem({
    // FUNCTION CALLBACK
    @required this.onTapRestaurantItemCallback,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      // FUNCTION CALLBACK
      onTap: onTapRestaurantItemCallback,

// CONTAINING SCREEN WIDGET - USING WIDGET ABOVE
// .... //
RestaurantItem(
  // FUNCTION CALLBACK
  onTapRestaurantItemCallback: () => { // Handling the callback method }
),
```

Comment: `() => onTapRestaurantItemCallback` is a zero-argument function that returns a function. Since you want to *invoke* `onTapRestaurantItemCallback`, that should be `() => onTapRestaurantItemCallback()`.   Is your callback `async`?  Why does it return a `Future`?

Comment: Great. You solved my problem. This works:                                                           
onTap: () => onTapRestaurantItemCallback()                                                                    How do I put you as the provider of the answer?